# Webpack - Loading modules without creating an alias

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm just getting started with Webpack and have hit a snag.

I store my modules in `assets/js/someModule.js`. For example, here's a `loadSnaps` module I'm working on (AMD).

```
define('loadSnaps', ['jquery'], function($) {
    // Load latest snaps into DOM
});
```

In my `webpack.config.js` I create an alias to this module:

```
...

resolve: {
    alias: {
        loadSnaps: 'assets/js/loadSnaps.js'
    }
}

...
```

I'd like to know, is there an easier way of doing this without having to create an alias each time? Is it possible to specify the path of my modules so that I can just `require` them via there name?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `resolve.root`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve('./assets/js')
        ]
    }
};
```